# I would like help with a translation for “remember your purpose” or something similar

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, motto

After a particularly painful life shakeup, I want a tattoo that reminds me every day what I am supposed to do going forward.

I would like it to be “remember your purpose” or “remember why” or something else very similar.

If someone could help me with this, I would be deeply appreciative. I have no experience with Latin.

Answer (score 5):

*Finem tuum memento*.

This is a variant of Manuel's suggestion. Here *finem* means "end" in the philosophical sense.

The meaning of *finis* (accusative *finem*) is given [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfinis).

Answer (score 3):

Memento propositi tui/
Memento propositum tuum

"Tene propositum(tuum)" "keep to your purpose"